# Is it possible to index views in Apache Solr

Tags: sql, view, solr

Let me first give you an example. I have two tables -`table1` and `table2`. `table1` has a field `id_table2`, which is a foreign key and references one of the fields in `table2`. So, when I want to scan `table1`, I make a query like:

```
SELECT t1.attr_1_, t1.attr_2_, t2.attr_3_ FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id_table2 = t2.id
```

I'm eager to know whether it is technically possible to index this kind of data (not raw data, given by simple select * from table, but given by this view) in `Apache Solr`.

Comment: Yes - there are several ways to load the Solr index.  You are not limited to `select * from table`

Comment: Is there any tutorial or example on this? Let it be MySQL tables, Postgres, Oracle or other, where one has to load data, provided by views

Comment: Look at the docs to start - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Indexing+and+Basic+Data+Operations

Comment: Does this help? [link]https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the data import handler and set the "query" to point to your view. See example below:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:hsqldb:/temp/example/ex" user="sa" />
<document name="products">
<entity name="feature" query="SELECT * FROM MyView">
    <field column="attr_1" name="Attr1" />
    <field column="attr_2" name="Attr2" />
    <field column="attr_3" name="Attr3" />
</entity>
```